# Have three different search results using sqlite

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel-blade

I am wanting to show a set of results based on what it's privacy type is.

I am using lavavel 4.2, php, blade and sqlite.

I have public, friends, and private.
Public anyone can read, friends only author and friends can read and private only the author can read it.

The site has a log in/ out functionality.

Can this be done with one sqlite query?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can do it using `UNION ALL` to combine the results of multiple queries. here's an example:

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE is_private="1"
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE is_public="1"
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE is_mine="1"
GROUP BY friends.user_id -- optionally remove duplicates
```

please note, `--` denotes a comment in SQL

Comment: Thanks. I thought it would be easy enough. 

It is not just from friends, there are none friends in public and private is user only. Friends has only the list of relationships. 

But that UNION all looks like a good start.

Comment: You could also remove duplicates by using UNION instead of UNION ALL.

Comment: @RichardLawton if the table has different column names, you should use aliases like `SELECT first_name AS friend_name`. in this way you can ensure all your tables will share common column names in the results.